# Open content of link on the same page

Tags: php, html, css

How to open a link from the same page, or should I say display the content of that link on the same page where the link is, I haven't tried anything yet cause I really don't know what this sort of thing is called, I'm new at web developing I really need this one cause it can make the website that I'm working on right now look more professional 
here is an accurate picture/explanation for what I want: 
[Picture of what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPD3v.png)

Comment: Search `iframe`

Comment: thank you, let me check on that one

Answer (score 1):

You could do it using some jquery:

Take the code below as a reference:

```js
$('#link1').on('click',function(){
    $('#content1').css('display', 'inline');
    $('#content2').css('display', 'none');
});

$('#link2').on('click',function(){
    $('#content1').css('display', 'none');
    $('#content2').css('display', 'inline');
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #cacaca;
  width: 350px;
  height: 150px;
}

.container {
  display: relative;
  float: left;
  background: #9A9ACA;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

#content1, #content2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="content1">
      Some content
    </div>
    <div id="content2">
      Other stuff
    </div>
  </div>
  <div><a href="#" id="link1">Link1</a></div>
  <div><a href="#" id="link2">Link2</a></div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Use a browser side application like `jQuery` to change the CSS `class` or `id` from hidden to shown 'onmousedown'. Place your div style as hidden initially, then write jQuery to show the div on press of your mouse button.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>toggle demo</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<p style="display: none">THE AWESOME SAUCE!</p>

<script>
$( "button" ).click(function() {
$( "p" ).toggle();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You need to do some studying up on JQuery for this purpose, luckily there are a lot of examples of this very topic out there for you to research, I suggest starting here: 
http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: what about if i wanna diplay image?

Answer (score -1):

you can redirect  the page by simply typing .....

```
  header("Location: file_name");
```

or you can give the HTML content by simply giving

```
   <a href ="localhost/8000/file_name">
```

Comment: The question is unclear without the image. Check the image attached

Comment: i just want to display on a box the main content for example : if the link 1 says "Hello World" i want to show the hello world of link 1 to the content box of the main page